# TransientObjectException on saving child object and parent already saved

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to save an object Alumne with a foreign key to Curs that is already created, but I'm getting org.hibernate.TransientObject.Exception.

One curs can have many alumnes.

I just want to save Alumne and the foreign key idCurs, Curs is already saved in database but I'm getting TransientObjectException in

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "idCurs")
```

I did not add any cascade because the Curs is already saved and I don't want to replace its data.

Am I missing something? Shold I query curs again?

**ERROR**

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: es.caib.accfor.ejb.aplicacions.alumne.entity.Alumne.curs -> es.caib.accfor.ejb.aplicacions.curs.entity.Curs
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: es.caib.accfor.ejb.aplicacions.alumne.entity.Alumne.curs -> es.caib.accfor.ejb.aplicacions.curs.entity.Curs
...
```

**Alumne.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Alumne")
public class Alumne implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ALU_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "AF_ACC_ALUMNE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "AF_ACC_ALUMNE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AF_ACC_ALUMNE_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ALU_AVALUACIO")
    private GruReg avaluacio;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "idCurs")
  private Curs curs;
 ...
```

**Curs.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CURS")
public class Curs implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "OFF_CODI")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "AF_ACC_CURSOS_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "AF_ACC_CURSOS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AF_ACC_CURSOS_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;
    ...
```

**AlumneService.java**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = Names.ALUMNE_SVC)
public class AlumneService extends BackService<Alumne> implements AlumneServiceInterface {
    public Alumne save(Alumne alumne) throws AppException {
        Alumne nou;

        if (eManager.contains(alumne)) {
            nou = eManager.merge(alumne);
        } else {
            eManager.persist(alumne);
            nou = alumne;
        }

        return nou;
    }
```

Comment: please post the code doing the save etc

Comment: Usually happens when relation entity null. check it

Answer (score 0):

Without your code it is hard to diagnose accurately but I'm fairly certain this is your problem.

In one hibernate session you load the Curs object from the database.

In a different session you create the Alumne object and set the Curs object on it. Because the Curs object is on on the *current* session it deems it to be transient.

What you need to do is ensure the Curs object is connected to the same session you are creating the Alumne object in. So load the Curs object and set it on the Alumne object in the same session you're saving the Alumne object.

That should solve your problem.